# Problem occurring when changing hash table size

Tags: data-structures, hash-tables

I'm practicing an exam for a data structures course. There's a question about a hash table with hash function:
$$h'(k,i)=h_1(k)+i*h_2(k) \mod{11}$$ where
$$h_1(k)=k \mod{13}$$ and $$h_2(k) = 1 + k \mod{7}$$

There's a question:
What problem will occur if we change the table size to 12 and we also change the module in $$h'(k,i)$$ to 12?

I thought that the new hash function outputs 0 on some occasions, although I don't really see why would it be any worse than 11, which would also output 0 sometimes.

Comment: Hint: investigate the distribution of elements. Note that in the setup, all three divisors are prime (before the change).

Comment: What is your goal?  Without a clear goal, any hash function is "good enough", even the one that gives 0 on any input.

Comment: The goal is to avoid collisions as much as possible, and evenly fill the table. I already got that those numbers are prime, but that doesn't help me much.

Comment: Could you edit your question to contain all the needed information in a clear and formal way?

Comment: @Raphael how would you go about finding out the distribution? If I do for i in range(200): (i %13) % 7 it gives a linear sequence which shows that it doesn't matter what you mod with. What sequence would you use to show the performance of this hash in terms of collision rate?

Comment: @user1932405 I don't see how `(i %13) % 7` relates to the question. You want to count how many $k$ map to which index for which $i$.